# Tag wiki text box goes under the "how to edit a wiki" box.

Tags: bug, status-completed

The excerpt text box is too long, and it runs underneath the "How to edit a tag wiki" box.

[image: bug picture]

This is on ubuntu 10.10 with Firefox 3.6.13.

Comment: Also on FF 4.0b11 using Ubuntu 11.04alpha. Works as expected on FF4.0b11/Win7, though.

Comment: I second that. I also have Ubuntu 10.10 with Firefox 3.6.13. Thanks Seamus for opening this post, I wanted to do the same for a few days but never came to it.

Comment: Works as expected in FF 3.6.13 on Mac OS X.

Comment: having trouble reproing this on my windows box, any windows repro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Seems to be fixed now.