# Text box for post flagging dialog goes outside the dialog borders

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Edit box on the "flag" link for a post goes outside the "window" borders.

See below:

[image]

All similar flag dialogs in which there's an edit box are affected.

Reproducible on both main site and meta, using both Firefox 3.6 and Chromium 9.0 on Ubuntu 10.10. **Not** reproducible on Chrome 10/Firefox 4.0b12/IE9 on Windows 7.

Possibly related: [this issue](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/tag-wiki-text-box-goes-under-the-how-to-edit-a-wiki-box) from a week or so ago (the same pattern of OSes being affected).

Comment: Yes, it happens for me too (Ubuntu 10.10, Firefox 3.6.14), both on the main site and meta. The fix for http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/tag-wiki-text-box-goes-under-the-how-to-edit-a-wiki-box might have actually caused this issue.

Comment: I can repro. the fix is coming soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed as of rev 2011.3.11.9

Tested in both Chromium 9.0 and Firefox 3.6.14 on Ubuntu 10.10